# Fsck finds errors in OS, but not using LiveCD

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ext4, fsck, live-cd

Running fsck on a booted machine yields errors on the root file system. In an attempt to fix this, I booted from a LiveCD - but fsck on the LiveCD instance doesn't find any errors at all. I also tried running the same binary which a booted system would - with the same results of 0 errors.

What's going on here? How to fix the errors reported? (see below)

The machine is a headless Ubuntu 14.04, and the LiveCD is from Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition.

When I'm running:

```
fsck -v -n /dev/mapper/lvm-root -f
```

The response is:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Warning!  /dev/mapper/lvm-root is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(24598720--24598781) +(42616517--42616542) -(47432723--47432748) +(49925184--49925211) +(49925312--49925373)
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #750 (22700, counted=22638).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #1300 (13150, counted=13176).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #1447 (24124, counted=24098).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #1523 (32016, counted=32106).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong (30301182, counted=30319341).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -11927698 +11927700
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (15762199, counted=15762204).
Fix? no


/dev/mapper/lvm-root: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********


      130281 inodes used (0.82%, out of 15892480)
        1113 non-contiguous files (0.9%)
         112 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 121424/640
    33268738 blocks used (52.33%, out of 63569920)
           0 bad blocks
           3 large files

      101907 regular files
       19700 directories
           2 character device files
           0 block device files
           2 fifos
          22 links
        8624 symbolic links (8166 fast symbolic links)
          32 sockets
------------
      130289 files
```

As an attempt to fix this, I booted from from Ubuntu 14.04 LiveCD and ran the same command:

```
root@ubuntu:~# fsck -n -v /dev/mapper/lvm-root -f
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Warning!  /dev/mapper/lvm-root is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

      130281 inodes used (0.82%, out of 15892480)
        1114 non-contiguous files (0.9%)
         112 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 121429/640
    33268738 blocks used (52.33%, out of 63569920)
           0 bad blocks
           3 large files

      101908 regular files
       19704 directories
           2 character device files
           0 block device files
           2 fifos
          22 links
        8625 symbolic links (8167 fast symbolic links)
          31 sockets
------------
      130294 files
```

No errors, which I found weird. So I attempted to mount the root partition, and manually run the fsck located under /sbin/fsck:

```
root@ubuntu:~# /mnt/sbin/fsck -n -v /dev/mapper/lvm-root -f
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Warning!  /dev/mapper/lvm-root is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

      130281 inodes used (0.82%, out of 15892480)
        1114 non-contiguous files (0.9%)
         112 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 121429/640
    33268738 blocks used (52.33%, out of 63569920)
           0 bad blocks
           3 large files

      101908 regular files
       19704 directories
           2 character device files
           0 block device files
           2 fifos
          22 links
        8625 symbolic links (8167 fast symbolic links)
          31 sockets
------------
      130294 files
```

Comment: Have the same issue. I believe it is even blocking the backup process of this VM (qemu). Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Running fsck on a mounted filesystem will show the same errors that will occur if you poweroff the system at that moment; the state on disk is inconsistent because updates will have been buffered in memory and not yet been written out to disk. Hence ***DO NOT DO THIS!***

Only run fsck on unmounted filesystems. Even on read-only mounted filesystems problems can occur if fsck fixes problems and the kernel doesn't know about it.

Comment: Whether the system is mounted or not doesn't make any difference on the LiveCD. Also not writing any changes using fsck with the -n flag